# How to implement passportjs's successRedirect in nestjs module?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, passport.js

All I want to do is auth user with some passport strategy, get user's data saved in backend and return user data to client.

All good with backend side, user data collected and saved but how to pass user data to client after that?

Comment: If you're implementing the passport module yourself, maybe try to use the nestjs package for passport (https://github.com/nestjs/passport). It also includes some examples to get you started.

Comment: Otherwise your question is very bare bones. I'd suggest adding your current code (trimed down to essential parts) and trying to explain what is it exactly you want to achive. e.g. what kind of auth are you using? What user data do you want to return? The information like name, email etc. or just the session to authenticate further requests with?

Comment: I'm implementing google-auth-20 passport package. I'll add some code, but my question is about: how to send received in /callback data to client, so I can finish auth for user.
Client(reactjs) initiate auth session, then I getting to google page, login user and google redirects me to /callback route, where I see response from backend. But I need this response being redirected to client.